# First index appearance in a string recursive

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Im trying to write a recursive function that gets as an input a string and a char. the function return the first index appearance of the char in the string. If the char doesnt appear it returns None.
I have a problem only with returning None. In my case when the char isnt in the string the function throws an error, any advice?

```
def char_first_index(s,c):
    if len_rec(s)==0:
        return None
    if s[0]==c:
        return  0
    return 1+ char_first_index(s[1:],c)
```

Comment: And that error is ... ?  Also, what is `len_rec`?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: This is because only for the last call, the one on the empty string, you return `None`. But all the previous calls return 1 + something. This results in something such as `1 + 1 + 1 + ... + None`. And you can't add `None` to an integer. You will need to redesign the function, I'm afraid. How about returning `-float("Infinity")` if the character is in the string, so the user can check if the value is `< 0` or instead return `1` and require the user to check if the result is bigger than the length of the string. It generally is a good idea to always return objects of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new slice at each iteration, and you have to add 1 for each recursion. Instead, recurse on the index:

```
def char_first_index(s, c, index = 0):
    if len(s) == index:
        return None
    if s[index] == c:
        return index
    return char_first_index(s, c, index + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the character is not in the input, your function tries to perform `1+None`, hence the error. Try this instead:

```
def char_first_index(s,c):
    if len_rec(s)==0:
        return None
    if s[0]==c:
        return  0
    answer =  char_first_index(s[1:],c)
    if answer is not None:
        return 1+answer
    else:
        return answer
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'm assuming `len_rec` is a recursive function that gets the length of the string; you haven't written it so I've just changed it to `len()` for testing.

Secondly, I'm not sure how this function is supposed to handle the character not being in the string, as that will mean trying to add `None` to a number.

Here is an amended function that still uses your count idea, but handles the case of a `None` being returned:

```
def char_first_index(s,c):
    if len(s)==0:
        return None
    elif s[0]==c:
        return 0
    else:
        count = char_first_index(s[1:], c)
        if count != None:
            return count + 1
        else:
            return None
```